# upgrade from 16.04 to 16.04.1 does not happen

Tags: apt, 16.04, upgrade

Voilla, after some pain about 14.04 not being able to start the upgrade, once started it finished fine:

[image]

But now:

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04 LTS"

$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release
Reading package lists... Done 

$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  playonlinux
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

Puzzled. Can anyone delineate what's going on?

Comment: P.S. is upgrading to the point 1 release really a good idea?

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the contents of your `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: @edwinksl Yep, and it's really short: 
`deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main universe restricted multiverse`

Comment: Hi Matt, In the beginning of you post, must we read 14.4 or 16.4?

Comment: @J.Chomel the versions as written. double checked it. upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04 finished just fine (what a surprise) but now how do I upgrade to 16.04.1?

Answer (score 4):

From your 1st comment:

> Yep, and it's really short: deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main universe restricted multiverse

Your settings are probably wrong.

I am missing a few repositories that I would assume should be active ...

```
xenial-security universe
xenial-security multiverse
xenial multiverse
xenial-updates multiverse
```

Check these 2 pages with settings at dash, search "software&updates":

[image]

- I would myself always tick the 1st 2. 3rd too but is always optional (if you want to keep your system pure keep it off). The 4th is als optional.
- "download from" I have set as "netherlands". Check you have either "main" or a good working mirror near you.

[image]

- you need the 1st 2 checkboxes ticked. 3rd one is optional
- bottom select probably needs to be active too.